# Implement rank function (rank over partition by) in impala 1.2.4?

Tags: java, jar, impala

I am not able to find Partition and Rank function in impala (version 1.2.4) so far. Is there any way to implement it?

Also I can't update impala version as I am using amazon web services.

Answer (score 0):

Analytic window functions will be released with Impala 2.0 in the next few months. If you'd like to see how we implemented rank(), check out [the commit](https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/commit/137bb45d81ea57655aefbf5cde0cbeab0121b8f0) on the Impala github.

Comment: sounds great..!! but we will be moving into production by next month . so is there any compiled version of this (.so or .ll file)  that i can run it in impala 1.2.4 by creating temporary function or by any other means ?

Comment: No, unfortunately there won't be a way to make this work with Impala 1.2.4 without a massive amount of work back-porting changes yourself.

Comment: Thanks, will try figuring out something.